# How to tag questions about boat travel on rivers & lakes?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Consider this question: [Boat from Phnom Penh to Siem Reap in April](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/boat-from-phnom-pehn-to-siem-reap-in-april)

OP created a new tag [boat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boat), but that's not a good solution, since there's already [boats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boats). Surely [boat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boat) & [boats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boats) should point to the same tag.

**Thing is, [boats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boats) is currently synonym for [sea-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-travel).**

Of course, that's a "[river-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/river-travel)" question, not [sea-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-travel) one!

Any ideas? Here are some options I could think of:

- [water-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-travel)? :-P Seems clumsy.
- Ignore the difference, and call travel on any body of water "sea travel"?
- Make [boats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boats) the main tag, so it covers seas, lakes, rivers, canals, etc?
- Use [riverboats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riverboats) for questions like this?

Answer (score 2):

I was about to say I like [riverboats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riverboats) as an answer, but then wondered about [canalboats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canalboats) in the UK, for example.

Perhaps we do have [boats](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boats) as the overall tag, and then add [oceans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceans) or [rivers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rivers) or [lakes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lakes) or [canals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canals) as as secondary tag?

Still musing on this...

Comment: `boats` as main tag would probably work fine, usually even without secondary tag. (In the "Boat from Phnom Pehn to Siem Reap" question, for example, `river` wouldn't add much value.)  But then, should we leave `ferries` alone, or also make that a synonym of `boats`? :-)

Comment: Bah go and make all those singular tags then, I give up trying to keep our tags tidy. d-;

Comment: @hippietrail - sorry updated ;)  I should be excused for any posts made after 11pm.

Comment: Just don't make any tags after 11pm then d-;

Comment: I wish I could tag people.... ;)